# ethers - call an overloaded function with a specific signer

Tags: contract-invocation, ethers.js, function-override

Connecting a specific signer to a contract object in [Ethers](https://docs.ethers.io) is easy:

```js
// assuming a signer called 'user' and a contract called 'Foo' with function 'bar'
await Foo.connect(user).bar();
```

There's also clear guidance on the issues that sometimes happen with function overloading in Ethers [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/migration/web3/#migration-from-web3-js--contracts--overloaded-functions), to take an example from the ERC721 interface:

```js
// assuming an ERC721 nft contract called 'NFT'
await NFT['safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)'](
  sender.address, 
  recipient.address, 
  ethers.BigNumber.from("1")
);
// or
await NFT['safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256,bytes)'](
  sender.address,
  recipient.address,
  ethers.BigNumber.from("1"),
  "0x"
);
```

But how do you connect a specific signer to an overloaded function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took a fair amount of playing around, but finally discovered that:

```js
await NFT.connect(sender)['safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)'](
  sender.address, 
  recipient.address, 
  ethers.BigNumber.from("1")
);
```

is the winning combination. Don't put a `.` after `connect(sender)`.